# How to get last sms from the device?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application which must recognize SMS commands. So, I need to know how I can get the last sms. I know that I need to use BroadcastReceiver (and I use it), but I don't know how I can get the last sms in this class. Please, help me with it, I hope you can do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you checkout this tutorial: http://blog.evoxmusic.fr/dev/android-content-observer-get-the-last-sms-sent-and-avoid-multiple-wrong-pickup.html Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: Check this Link for [SmsAutoReceiver](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/create-an-application-auto-receiving-new-message-sms/) Link contains code for [SmsAutoReceiver](http://code.google.com/p/android-newbie-sourcecode/source/browse/trunk/SmsAutoReceiver/).. Check out this code , this code will help you to get last SMS you received.

Comment: You are wanting to read last short messages or you want to program sms receiver ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below code it may help you.

```
                    Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

                    ContentResolver cr = con.getContentResolver();
                    Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] { "_id",
                            "address", "date", "body", "read" }, null,
                            null, null);

                    startManagingCursor(c);
                    Main_calss.getSmsLogs(c, con);
```

---

```
public static final ArrayList<String> sms_num = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final ArrayList<String> sms_body = new ArrayList<String>();


public static void getSmsLogs(Cursor c, Context con) {

    if (sms_num.size() > 0) {
        sms_num.clear();
        sms_body.clear();
    }

    try {

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("error",
                        ""
                                + c.getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
                    c.moveToNext();
                    continue;
                }

                String Number = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                String Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                        .toString();

                sms_num.add(Number);

                sms_body.add(Body);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now get last massage you have to do this.

```
sms_num.get(sms_num.size()-1);
sms_body.get(sms_num.size()-1);
```

if it is correct then make it right.

Answer (score 2):

thanks Bo for the link to my blog.

To get the last message from your embeded android database (sqlite) you have at first create a cursor instance.

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query("content://sms", null, null, null, null);
```

and then move to the first sms (the first is the last receiver ;))

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Look at my blog how I did it as Bo told you ;)

// removed link

Cheers